# JWildCardHandler Internal 500 Error when submitting form

Tags: coldfusion, iis-7.5

We are getting this relentless 500 error on a coldfusion site. We are using Coldfusion 9.0.1 and only when we submit a form to update a database table we get this error. Only one page causes it, but there is nothing in the logs indicating what happened.

I turned on detailed errors for this one site and I see that the error is caused by the JWildCardHandler with error code 0x00000000.

I've checked permissions on everything. Even on the Access DB that is being used.

I tried this same code and database on another server and I receive no error at all. I tried making sure the config was the exact same for IIS and CF on both servers and still get the error.

Any ideas? There just seems to be no reason that it's throwing this error.

Here is the form processing page that is causing the error. Really not much, just some basic queries:

```
<cfquery datasource="#Datasource#" name="UpdateTheTable">
    UPDATE Our_table SET 
    #Est# = #PreserveSingleQuotes(EstValue)#,
    Username = '#CurrentUser.Username#',
    DateCurrent = NOW()
    WHERE Attribute1=#CurrentUser.Attribute1ID# AND Attribute2=#Attribute2ID#;
</cfquery>
```

Here is our stack trace:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet type='text/xsl' href='freb.xsl'?>
<!-- saved from url=(0014)about:internet -->
<failedRequest url="http://oursite.domain.com:80/subdir/index.cfm"
               siteId="8"
               appPoolId="subdir"
               processId="13528"
               verb="POST"
               remoteUserName=""
               userName=""
               tokenUserName="NT AUTHORITY\IUSR"
               authenticationType="anonymous"
               activityId="{00000000-0000-0000-7E06-0080000000E2}"
               failureReason="STATUS_CODE"
               statusCode="500"
               triggerStatusCode="500"
               timeTaken="202"
               xmlns:freb="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2006/06/iis/freb"
               >
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
 <System>
  <Provider Name="WWW Server" Guid="{3A2A4E84-4C21-4981-AE10-3FDA0D9B0F83}"/>
  <EventID>0</EventID>
  <Version>1</Version>
  <Level>0</Level>
  <Opcode>1</Opcode>
  <Keywords>0x0</Keywords>
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2013-04-22T13:36:17.490Z"/>
  <Correlation ActivityID="{00000000-0000-0000-7E06-0080000000E2}"/>
  <Execution ProcessID="13528" ThreadID="13628"/>
  <Computer>Server1</Computer>
 </System>
 <EventData>
  <Data Name="ContextId">{00000000-0000-0000-7E06-0080000000E2}</Data>
  <Data Name="SiteId">8</Data>
  <Data Name="AppPoolId">subdir</Data>
  <Data Name="ConnId">1610614393</Data>
  <Data Name="RawConnId">0</Data>
  <Data Name="RequestURL">http://oursite.domain.com:80/subdir/index.cfm</Data>
  <Data Name="RequestVerb">POST</Data>
 </EventData>
 <RenderingInfo Culture="en-US">
  <Opcode>GENERAL_REQUEST_START</Opcode>
 </RenderingInfo>
 <ExtendedTracingInfo xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/trace">
  <EventGuid>{D42CF7EF-DE92-473E-8B6C-621EA663113A}</EventGuid>
 </ExtendedTracingInfo>
</Event>
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
 <System>
  <Provider Name="WWW Server" Guid="{3A2A4E84-4C21-4981-AE10-3FDA0D9B0F83}"/>
  <EventID>0</EventID>
  <Version>1</Version>
  <Level>0</Level>
  <Opcode>12</Opcode>
  <Keywords>0x0</Keywords>
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2013-04-22T13:36:17.490Z"/>
  <Correlation ActivityID="{00000000-0000-0000-7E06-0080000000E2}"/>
  <Execution ProcessID="13528" ThreadID="13628"/>
  <Computer>Server1</Computer>
 </System>
 <EventData>
  <Data Name="ContextId">{00000000-0000-0000-7E06-0080000000E2}</Data>
 </EventData>
 <RenderingInfo Culture="en-US">
  <Opcode>GENERAL_ISAPI_HANDLER</Opcode>
 </RenderingInfo>
 <ExtendedTracingInfo xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/trace">
  <EventGuid>{D42CF7EF-DE92-473E-8B6C-621EA663113A}</EventGuid>
 </ExtendedTracingInfo>
</Event>
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
 <System>
  <Provider Name="WWW Server" Guid="{3A2A4E84-4C21-4981-AE10-3FDA0D9B0F83}"/>
  <EventID>0</EventID>
  <Version>1</Version>
  <Level>0</Level>
  <Opcode>1</Opcode>
  <Keywords>0x0</Keywords>
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2013-04-22T13:36:17.599Z"/>
  <Correlation ActivityID="{00000000-0000-0000-7E06-0080000000E2}"/>
  <Execution ProcessID="13528" ThreadID="13628"/>
  <Computer>Server1</Computer>
 </System>
 <EventData>
  <Data Name="ContextId">{00000000-0000-0000-7E06-0080000000E2}</Data>
 </EventData>
 <RenderingInfo Culture="en-US">
  <Opcode>ISAPI_START</Opcode>
 </RenderingInfo>
 <ExtendedTracingInfo xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/trace">
  <EventGuid>{2E94E6C7-EDA0-4B73-9010-2529EDCE1C27}</EventGuid>
 </ExtendedTracingInfo>
</Event>
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
 <System>
  <Provider Name="ISAPI Extension" Guid="{A1C2040E-8840-4C31-BA11-9871031A19EA}"/>
  <EventID>0</EventID>
  <Version>1</Version>
  <Level>0</Level>
  <Opcode>1</Opcode>
  <Keywords>0x0</Keywords>
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2013-04-22T13:36:17.599Z"/>
  <Correlation ActivityID="{00000000-0000-0000-7E06-0080000000E2}"/>
  <Execution ProcessID="13528" ThreadID="13628"/>
  <Computer>Server1</Computer>
 </System>
 <EventData>
  <Data Name="ContextId">{00000000-0000-0000-7E06-0080000000E2}</Data>
  <Data Name="DllName">C:\ColdFusion9\runtime\lib\wsconfig\1\jrun_iis6_wildcard.dll</Data>
 </EventData>
 <RenderingInfo Culture="en-US">
  <Opcode>CALL_ISAPI_EXTENSION</Opcode>
 </RenderingInfo>
 <ExtendedTracingInfo xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/trace">
  <EventGuid>{ACADE3B2-B7D7-4339-956C-811B4EDB1B24}</EventGuid>
 </ExtendedTracingInfo>
</Event>
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
 <System>
  <Provider Name="ISAPI Extension" Guid="{A1C2040E-8840-4C31-BA11-9871031A19EA}"/>
  <EventID>0</EventID>
  <Version>1</Version>
  <Level>0</Level>
  <Opcode>2</Opcode>
  <Keywords>0x0</Keywords>
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2013-04-22T13:36:17.614Z"/>
  <Correlation ActivityID="{00000000-0000-0000-7E06-0080000000E2}"/>
  <Execution ProcessID="13528" ThreadID="13628"/>
  <Computer>Server1</Computer>
 </System>
 <EventData>
  <Data Name="ContextId">{00000000-0000-0000-7E06-0080000000E2}</Data>
 </EventData>
 <RenderingInfo Culture="en-US">
  <Opcode>ISAPI_EXTENSION_DONE</Opcode>
 </RenderingInfo>
 <ExtendedTracingInfo xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/trace">
  <EventGuid>{ACADE3B2-B7D7-4339-956C-811B4EDB1B24}</EventGuid>
 </ExtendedTracingInfo>
</Event>
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
 <System>
  <Provider Name="WWW Server" Guid="{3A2A4E84-4C21-4981-AE10-3FDA0D9B0F83}"/>
  <EventID>0</EventID>
  <Version>1</Version>
  <Level>0</Level>
  <Opcode>2</Opcode>
  <Keywords>0x0</Keywords>
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2013-04-22T13:36:17.614Z"/>
  <Correlation ActivityID="{00000000-0000-0000-7E06-0080000000E2}"/>
  <Execution ProcessID="13528" ThreadID="13628"/>
  <Computer>Server1</Computer>
 </System>
 <EventData>
  <Data Name="ContextId">{00000000-0000-0000-7E06-0080000000E2}</Data>
 </EventData>
 <RenderingInfo Culture="en-US">
  <Opcode>ISAPI_END</Opcode>
 </RenderingInfo>
 <ExtendedTracingInfo xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/trace">
  <EventGuid>{2E94E6C7-EDA0-4B73-9010-2529EDCE1C27}</EventGuid>
 </ExtendedTracingInfo>
</Event>
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
 <System>
  <Provider Name="WWW Server" Guid="{3A2A4E84-4C21-4981-AE10-3FDA0D9B0F83}"/>
  <EventID>0</EventID>
  <Version>1</Version>
  <Level>0</Level>
  <Opcode>33</Opcode>
  <Keywords>0x0</Keywords>
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2013-04-22T13:36:17.614Z"/>
  <Correlation ActivityID="{00000000-0000-0000-7E06-0080000000E2}"/>
  <Execution ProcessID="13528" ThreadID="13628"/>
  <Computer>Server1</Computer>
 </System>
 <EventData>
  <Data Name="ContextId">{00000000-0000-0000-7E06-0080000000E2}</Data>
  <Data Name="HttpStatus">500</Data>
  <Data Name="HttpSubStatus">0</Data>
  <Data Name="FileNameOrURL">500.htm</Data>
 </EventData>
 <RenderingInfo Culture="en-US">
  <Opcode>GENERAL_SEND_CUSTOM_ERROR</Opcode>
 </RenderingInfo>
 <ExtendedTracingInfo xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/trace">
  <EventGuid>{D42CF7EF-DE92-473E-8B6C-621EA663113A}</EventGuid>
 </ExtendedTracingInfo>
</Event>
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
 <System>
  <Provider Name="WWW Server" Guid="{3A2A4E84-4C21-4981-AE10-3FDA0D9B0F83}"/>
  <EventID>0</EventID>
  <Version>1</Version>
  <Level>0</Level>
  <Opcode>2</Opcode>
  <Keywords>0x0</Keywords>
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2013-04-22T13:36:17.692Z"/>
  <Correlation ActivityID="{00000000-0000-0000-7E06-0080000000E2}"/>
  <Execution ProcessID="13528" ThreadID="13628"/>
  <Computer>Server1</Computer>
 </System>
 <EventData>
  <Data Name="ContextId">{00000000-0000-0000-7E06-0080000000E2}</Data>
  <Data Name="BytesSent">6428</Data>
  <Data Name="BytesReceived">4864</Data>
  <Data Name="HttpStatus">500</Data>
  <Data Name="HttpSubStatus">0</Data>
 </EventData>
 <RenderingInfo Culture="en-US">
  <Opcode>GENERAL_REQUEST_END</Opcode>
 </RenderingInfo>
 <ExtendedTracingInfo xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/trace">
  <EventGuid>{D42CF7EF-DE92-473E-8B6C-621EA663113A}</EventGuid>
 </ExtendedTracingInfo>
</Event>
</failedRequest>
```

Comment: Can you post the code and the full error including the top 20-odd entries of the stack trace. Which logs did you check (list them, please). Have you googled "JWildCardHandler error", and were there any useful suggestions and did you act on any of them? What troubleshooting steps have you thusfar tried (other than the ones listed)?

Comment: I checked all of the logs in CF Admin, IIS Logs for the site and I turned on Failed Request Tracing.

I've Googled this issue many times with no help. Most people have a different error code. I've tried all suggestions anyway.

Steps I have taken are:

- Tried switching between 32 and 64 bit mode in the app pool. The site doesn't work at all when 32 bit apps are enabled

- Tried matching the environment settings in our other server. Even switching CF to use Java 1.7 instead of it's internal JVM like our other server

-I gave the site folders and database directories full Everyone permissions

Comment: I also tested other pages that submit data to the same exact form processing page and they all work except this one.

- Restarted CF, Restarted IIS

- I also tried disconnecting CF from IIS and reconnecting

I'll try to get the code posted soon.

Comment: Here is the full error that comes up:

Module IsapiModule
Notification ExecuteRequestHandler
Handler JWildCardHandler
Error Code 0x00000000
Requested URL http://oursite.domain.com:80/subdir/index.cfm
Physical Path C:\inetpub\wwwroot\oursite.domain.com\subdir\index.cfm
Logon Method Anonymous
Logon User Anonymous
Failed Request Tracing Log Directory C:\inetpub\logs\FailedReqLogFiles

Comment: Is ColdFusion running as the same user on both of your servers?  Is the Access DB on the same server as ColdFusion?  Can you query the database or do all database transaction attempts fail?  Can you show us any errors from your "cfusion-out.log" file?

Comment: Please update the question, rather than adding that extra info to the comments: people won't necessarily see the comments. That error message... is that what you're seeing on the browser? It doesn't look like the sort of thing one would normally see returned by CF to the browser. Ditto the stack trace: that doesn't look like the stack trace Java generates.

Comment: Have you checked to make sure you are not posting more than 100 fields? Some of the more recent CF patches added a default limit of 100 fields

Comment: Thank you for the responses. @Miguel-F  CF is running the same on both servers. I noticed on the server that is working the "Interact with desktop" option was clicked, so I did this on the other server and it didn't do anything. This error comes up since I turned on detailed errors in IIS before it just said 500 internal server error. I don't see a cousin-out.log file on our server anywhere.

Comment: @AdamCameron Yes, I see the error message in my browser. It is the Failed Request Trace log from IIS. Where would I look for the stack trace from Java?

Comment: @JamesMohler The form is no bigger than 50 fields.

Comment: The "cfusion-out.log" is on the ColdFusion server and will contain any errors, including the stack trace. Depending on your installation type, server versus j2ee, the log file will be in `{cf_root}\runtime\logs\coldfusion-out.log` or `jrun4\logs\cfusion-out.log`.

Comment: Well, it turns out that the the 500 error was caused by having the postSizeLimit too low in the neo-runtime.xml file. Now, the forms submit, but I get a white blank page. It never ends.......

Comment: The cfusion-out.log has this line repetitively:
04/26 12:34:47 Error [jrpp-0] - File not found: /lb_check.cfm The specific sequence of files included or processed is: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\lb_check.cfm''

I have no idea where that is coming from...

Answer (score 1):

I recently ran into the same problem, same error, same 0x00000000 error code, same even down to the occurrence on a single form (other forms were working fine). The problem boiled down to the "postParametersLimit" setting in CF's neo-runtime.xml. The form data was exceeding the limit, causing CF to reject the request, and surfacing the error at the point of the JWildCardHandler handler. I simply increased the postParametersLimit in neo-runtime (using Notepad, just do a text search for that parameter name in the xml file. You'll see the value for it. Change. Save.) and restarted the CF services. All is good. I am running 64bit CF9.0.2 on load-balanced 64bit Win2008 R2 servers. Good luck.